# Installing Wine 1.8 on Debian not working

Tags: debian, windows, executable, wine

I followed this link http://tecadmin.net/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-debian/# to install Wine on Debian 7.9 Wheezy but to no avail. When I reached step `sudo ./configure  --enable-win64` it asked for "flex" package and then for "bison" package. So I installed both using `sudo apt-get install flex` and the same for "bison"

Then after I pressed Enter executing this step `sudo make`, it gave so many lines after lines and I waited for almost 20 mins but it didn't stop load more lines like the following

[image]

I have the feeling, after trying many other links, that Wine can NOT be installed on Debian although posts say it can.

**Question: How can I install Wine on Debian?**

**Update & Edit:**

I've waited for around 35 mins and now it's finished. Then I typed `sudo make install`But now when I type `wine` in the shell, it gives me *command not found*

Answer (score 1):

You missed the last step in the instructions:

```
sudo make install
```

That should make Wine available on your system.

For Wheezy you could also just follow the [instructions given on the Wine website](http://wiki.winehq.org/Debian) itself; they provide pre-built packages:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
echo deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ wheezy main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winehq-devel
```

(although that install the current latest version of Wine, which is 1.9.0).

Debian does support Wine 1.8 but only on Stretch for now; there should be a Jessie backport soon, a Wheezy backport is unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I actually did the last step only forgot to mention... my mistake. Anyway, I'll try this WineHQ and let you know. Thanks again :)